# Ruby - ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and am attempting to run a program written long ago. I've installed Ruby 2.4.1 and the gem package (`test-unit 3.4.3`), but when I try to run the following command:

```
ruby ./run.rb test_5772.rb config_sprint210_uae.rb
```

Here I am passing two arguments to master ruby script (run.rb).  But I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught exception -- ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/optparse.rb:1631:in `permute!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/optparse.rb:1652:in `parse!'
    from /home/sadmin/SSN_FWQA/test-framework/lib/testrunner/arguments.rb:279:in `parse'
    from ./run.rb:76:in `<main>'
```

The same code is working fine with Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: Is that the whole error message? Ruby usually prints a long backtrace that points you to the source of the error, i.e. within `run.rb`.

Comment: Take a look at `run.rb` line 76 or `arguments.rb` line 279. If you need further help, post the code.

Comment: @Stefan actually same command and code is working fine with Ruby-1.8.7   But error is coming with ruby-2.4.1

Comment: I see two options: 1) you run the script under 1.8.7, or 2) you show the failing code so we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed now, its actually parse method issue because this API is receving arguments (argv) in a hash format but expecting an array. 
After making change in this API call, issue has been resolved.